# Find which column has unique values that can help distinguish the rows with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique

I have the following dataframe, which contains 2 rows:

```
index  name      food   color   number   year   hobby  music
0      Lorenzo   pasta  blue     5        1995  art    jazz
1      Lorenzo   pasta  blue     3        1995  art    jazz
```

I want to write a code that will be able to tell me **which column is the one that can distinguish between the these two rows.**
**For example , in this dataframe, the  column "number" is the one that distinguish between the two rows.**

Unti now I have done this very simply by just go over column after column using iloc and see the values.

```
duplicates.iloc[:,3]
>>>
0  blue
1  blue
```

It's important to take into account that:

1. This should be for loop, each time I check it on new generated dataframe.
2. There may be nore than 2 rows which I need to check
3. There may be more than 1 column that can distinguish between the rows.

I thought that the way to check such a thing will be something like take each time one column, get the unique values and check if they are equal to each other ,similarly to this:

```
for n in np.arange(0,len(df.columns)):
    tmp=df.iloc[:,n]
```

and then I thought to compare if all the values are similar to each other on the temporal dataframe, but here I got stuck because sometimes I have many rows and also I need.

**My end goal: to be able to check inside for loop to identify the column that has different values in each row of the temporaldtaframe, hence can help to distinguish between the rows.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `apply` the `duplicated` method on all columns:

```
s = df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated).any()

s[~s].index
```

Output: `['number']`

Comment: but sometimes  have more than 2 rows in the dataframe

Comment: @Reut ok I understood you wanted to compare 2 rows specifically

Comment: I want to compare each time whatever number of rows there are in the dataframe, here is two but as mentioned could be more

Comment: @Reut see update, if still not what you want please make the question more clear